# SQL Server RegExIndex CLR Returning Wrong Index Location

Tags: .net, sql-server, regex, clr

I have a SQL Server CLR in C# that functions like the SQL Server CHARINDEX function, but allows the use of Regular Expressions.

```
[SqlFunction]
public static SqlInt32 RegExIndex(SqlChars input, SqlString pattern, SqlInt32 beginning)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern.Value, Options);
    Match match = regex.Match(new string(input.Value), beginning.Value);
    return match.Index;
}
```

In testing, I found that the following returns 3 when it should return 1:

```
select dbo.RegExIndex('test', 't', 1)
```

The following returns 0 when it should return 4:

```
select dbo.RegExIndex('test', 't', 4)
```

I thought maybe the beginning parameter was zero base, but this also returns 0 when it should return 1:

```
select dbo.RegExIndex('test', 't', 0)
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Here's the updated code based on the answer provided:

```
[SqlFunction]
public static SqlInt32 RegExIndex(SqlChars input, SqlString pattern, SqlInt32 beginning)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern.Value, Options);
    return beginning.Value > input.Value.Length ? 0
        : !regex.Match(new string(input.Value), beginning.Value < 1 ? 0 : beginning.Value - 1).Success ? 0
        : regex.Match(new string(input.Value), beginning.Value < 1 ? 0 : beginning.Value - 1).Index + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using this [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3583dcyh.aspx) overload:

```
public Match Match(
    string input,
    int startat
)
```

where `startat` parameter (your `beginning` parameter) is a *zero-based character position at which to start the search*. Moreover, [`Match.Index`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index.aspx) property (your `match.Index` value) is also *zero-based starting position in the original string where the captured substring is found*.

This mean, in all your tests you get correct results:

```
select dbo.RegExIndex('test', 't', 1)
```

matches the last `t` (index = `3`);

```
select dbo.RegExIndex('test', 't', 4)
```

doesn't match anything;

```
select dbo.RegExIndex('test', 't', 0)
```

matches the first `t` (index = `0`).